# Android/Google TV STB or multimedia centre with HLS support

Tags: android, h.264, http-live-streaming, google-tv

Is anybody aware of the Android STB, that can be programmed, i.e allows .apk installation and has the built-in HLS support?

Regards,
STeN

Answer (score 2):

Android STBs using Sigma Designs chipsets should have HLS support. At least Sigma Designs was demoing that last year, and they told me it was part of the BSP that's provided to all STB makers.

For a specific vendor, [PeerTV](http://www.peertv.com/) told me they have HLS support. You probably will need to send a few emails and make a few calls to get solid answers. A lot of the STB makers on Alibaba will provide sample units for a low price.

Comment: Thanks for valuable tips! I will definitely check both. I was checking the Alibaba before and I have found couple of HLS STB's, but it was either the spare description or completely unknown brand offering everything for extremely low prices I did not trust...

Comment: @STen Yeah, Alibaba is like gambling.

Answer (score 0):

All Google TV devices allow the addition of user programs.  (They are both a development box and a user device).  Currently only Sony fully supports HLS.

Comment: Hi, I know about the Sony Google TV. But I need STB and the problem is I need the HLS as well. We are developing own HLS player component based on FFMPEG and we are almost done on mobile phones - we are optimizing it now for Tegra and Neon devices and it might be possible to run it on e.g. Logitech Revue, but I am not sure about the performance...